# Convert delimited record to seperate strings?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, type-conversion, calculation

On my web form I have a token box where the user can select multiple answers and it compiles them using a `~` to separate them. I am trying to add up a score on this page and I need to split those values. I tried using this and it says cannot explicitly convert char to string. Lets say the fields answer is `3~4~5`

How would I convert that to `3` `4` `5` in a manner that would allow me to perform a calculation.

```
string List1 = threeriskfactors.Text.ToString();
string[] Vals1 = List1.Split('~');
String name1 = List1[0];
String name2 = List1[1];
```

I have had no problems adding up single values from a drop down list but this is stumping me. For my other calculations my code looks like this:

```
int a1 = Convert.ToInt32(cancerisabnormalcells.SelectedValue.ToString());
int b1 = Convert.ToInt32(cancerissecondcause.SelectedValue.ToString());
int d1 = Convert.ToInt32(americancancersociety.SelectedValue.ToString());
int final1 = a1 + b1 + d1;
```

How do I split the token boxes value so I can add it to this calculation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the Sum of them then it is as simple as:

```
int final = List1.Split('~').Select(s => int.Parse(s)).Sum();
```

To Validate each value to see if it is parseable before parsing, you can use `ForEach` method of `List`:

```
List1.Split('~').ToList().ForEach(s => { int a =0; int.TryParse(s, out a); final +=a;  });
```

Comment: finally do .Sum() to get added result!

Comment: @DhanasekarSM thats what happens when you do not read question well. I thought he needs all the numbers to use them later. but just before you say it, I got that.

Comment: Thank you that worked. I have one other question to followup. It fails if the user does not put any answer in the token box. How could I check for nulls?

Comment: Where does it get final from? Thanks so much for the continued help. That doesnt seem to work tho.

Answer (score 0):

```
 IEnumerable<int> vals1 = list1.Select(e=> Convert.ToInt32(e));
int final1=0;
foreach(int val in vals1)
{
     final1 = final1 + val;
}
```

This should do it.

Answer (score 0):

```
var total = 0;

foreach (var item in list1.Split('~'))
    total += Int32.Parse(item);
```

By the way, I'm not sure how you're concatenating the values to get the tilde-delimited string. But, it's worth noting that HTML forms will automatically create  semicolon-delimited list of values from HTML form elements that share the same name.